GTM timer event not firing on specific page
I would like to create an event when a user spend 30 seconds in a specific web page. For that, I have created a GTM gtm.timer trigger. Testing in preview mode, it fires and works perfectly when I set page URL contains "/" (so all pages). However, if I just want it to fire the timer on an specific page, such as a blog post, by changing the page URL contains /en/blog/whateverURL it doesn´t fire anymore.
It´s interesting that I have seen/read thousands of videos and posts in Internet and I couldn´t find a single example of that. They all use contains "/" or matching regEx ".*"
By the way, I´m using an Angularjs single page application if that is important.
UPDATE
As requested I attach screenshots of tag and trigger configurations.
The page that should fire the trigger is www.domain.com/en/experiences
TAG

TRIGGER

UPDATE 2
I have found out something interesting. If I test from gtm connecting directly to the url: domain/en/experiences it works. However, if I connect directly from the root: / and navigate to the pages /en/experiences the trigger is not fired. I don´t know if this is the right behaviour and if that will work in production environment.

Can you provide more screenshots on how you set the trigger?

Screenshots attached

show a screenshot from the preview. It should indicate the reason for this trigger not to fire. If the reason is not matching page url, go to variables in the preview on the same event and check the value of the page url.

I have found out something interesting. If I test from gtm connecting directly to the url: domain/en/experiences it works. However, if I connect directly from the root: / and navigate to the pages /en/experiences the trigger is not fired. I don´t know if this is the right behaviour.

repost the comment : a quick guess. It's your website Single Page Application ? If yes, the time trigger can not be re-calculated if change page in SPA. The base logic here is Google Tag Manager JS needs to be reloaded. I think you need some extra custom JavaScript to do something similar
